# Calculating log odds of Y = 0 in Logistic Regression Model

Tags: logistic

For the following variables:

DV: YES/NO (1 vs. 0)
IV_1: Age
IV_2: MALE/FEMALE (1 vs. 0)

And co-efficients:

```
(Intercept)   -3.70     
Age            0.02     
Gender         0.17
```

I know that calculating the log odds of a YES (1) would require:

```
-3.70 + 0.02*Age + 0.17*Gender
```

But how would I calculate the log odds of a NO (0)?

Answer (score 4):

If $p$ represents the probability of YES, so that

$$\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$$

is the log odds of a YES, then $1-p$ is the probability of a NO.  This means that the log odds of a NO is

$$\log\left(\frac{1 - p}{1-(1-p)}\right) = \log\left(\frac{1 - p}{p}\right) = - \log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$$

So the log odds of a NO is the negative of the log odds of a YES.  Therefore, in the context of your logistic regression, the log odds of a NO is

$$
3.70 - 0.02 \times Age - 0.17 \times Gender
$$